# Create Custom Chatter Feed

Tags: chatter-feed, connect-api

I was recently tasked with retrieving chatter feeds addressed to the context User {'To Me' feeds}  and only those ('To Me' feeds) that were on Cases (standard Objects) that were 'Open' and getting to display those feeds in a separate window... I have tried using vf pages and apex controllers.. but I had to write a lot of code and then I can't get the view to display a Connect API Object...

Is there a way I can make use of the Connect API create stream method to achieve this...so that all forms of functionality is still available for the retrieved posts?

Comment: Do you want to retrieve or create chatter posts?

Comment: i want to retrieve first.. and be able to display the retrieved feeds in a seperate window

Comment: were you able to achieve it?

Comment: Yes i was able to retrieve. the project is also on hold at this time, but i think i know better now. the response comes in the form of JSON, and the information you need can be extracted via JSON class and methods